# How to sniff passwords remembered by applications?

Tags: encryption, passwords, disk-encryption, password-recovery, public-key-encryption

Suppose someone forgets their password for a web application such as gmail, facebook or some other application installed on the system such as skype, but the web browser or skype still remembers the password, but there is no way to read the password because it appears as a bunch of asterisks. Now suppose the user also forgot the recovery e-mail and or the password for the recovery email. The only way such a user can recover the password so as to be able to enter it on the same applications on their mobile phone, is to install a program on their PC to read the password data from the cache. At first, it may seem like the data can be recovered with a program like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), which analyzes network data, but upon second thought, one realizes that these applications will pass such passwords to an encrypting API such as [OpenSLL](https://www.openssl.org/) before passing the data over the network instead of transmitting it in raw format. So what is needed in this case is a program that will read the raw data from these program's (firefox, chrome, skype, etc...) cache, provided the information is not stored pre-encrypted on disk.

Where can I find such a program?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

I've posted an answer for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/242612/how-easy-is-it-to-recover-a-password-stored-in-an-application), which works in the case of some web browsers but not others. However, at the time I posted this question that answer was not present. Also, my question also covers Skype, which that question does not.

Regards.

Comment: you could try a debugging proxy like CharlesProxy, but it still may be very difficult to find the password in the stream, even if it is in plaintext. just install it, and point your app to the proxy. it will intercept all the traffic going through so you can sift through it. http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Tnank you for your reply. Unfortunately [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) can only be viewed to see the HTTP or HTTPS network data, and in the case of HTTPS the data will be encrypted before sending so it will be impossible to read the unencrypted password data (as is also the case with Wireshark). So, I am looking for a solution based on reading the data off the hard disk. Thanks.

Comment: the application itself is responsible for encrypting that data so that simple malware can't access a users set of passwords, and every application will store them differently, so you will need differant tools and techniques for each. here is one (questionable) utility for Skype: http://lastbit.com/skype/default.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How easy is it to recover a password stored in an application?](http://superuser.com/questions/242612/how-easy-is-it-to-recover-a-password-stored-in-an-application)

Comment: [NirSoft's Windows Password Recovery Tools](http://www.nirsoft.net/password_recovery_tools.html)

Comment: @FrankThomas, the [Skype Password](http://lastbit.com/skype/default.asp) application you mentioned is interesting, although from its description I can deduce that since skype stores hashes of passwords on disk, a malicious user need not use brute force to discover the pristine password characters. A hacker can much more easily modify the Skype executable so that it sends the hash of the password directly to the SKype server(s) to log in without requiring a password to be known. After all, since Skype stores this hash, it means it sends this hash to the server and not the original password.

Comment: @Techie007, the link you posted is probably one of the best collections of applications that read username and password information for various popular applications from disk. The site also has a link to the very interesting [Stellar Phoenix Password Revocery](http://www.stellar-info.com/password-recovery.php) application which can also be used to reset Windows passwords. A hacker could easily use a modified version of this software to backup a password, blank it, log in, and then restore the old password and delete the program. This way nobody would even know the hacker had logged in.

Comment: @JohnSonderson, be that as it may, it does underscores the point that password storage handling is an application-controlled phenomena, and as such there is no one-size-fits-all manner in which to access them. The info on skype is notable however. Usually, the idea is that neither the PC nor the server hold both the password and its recorded hash at the same time, except for the milliseconds during which a login is occurring. I suppose that means that if the skype database is taken, that everyone's skype account is instantly cracked, since in effect the password IS the hash.